How to handle error so that it stops function execution
It goes to the onError in the mutation, however in the try catch the next response has a status of 200 so it does not execute the catch method. What should I do so that if it goes to onError, it goes to catch.
I am also open to any solution that can correctly return/ end the function
const useValidatePassword = () =>{  
    return useMutation({
      mutationFn: async (data: any) => {
          const body: validatePasswordPayload = 
            {
               UserName: data.username,
               Password: data.currentPassword,
            };
         await apiAccountSettings.validatePassword(tenantName, body);
        }
      ,
      onSuccess: () => {
        return true
      },
      onError: (data) => {
        toast.error(t('Current password is incorrect'));
      },
      mutationKey: ['ValidatePassword', { tenant: tenantName }],
    });
}
       const {mutate: validatePassword, error} = useValidatePassword();

      Somefn()=>{
        try {
            await validatePassword(validatePayload);
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error(t("Something went wrong"));
            return
        }
      }


By throwing the error in the onError callback, you ensure that error is propagated to try-catch block.
new Promise wrapper around validatePassword call ensures that try-catch block can await result of mutation and catch any errors that are thrown.
const useValidatePassword = () => {
  return useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (data: any) => {
      const body: validatePasswordPayload = {
        UserName: data.username,
        Password: data.currentPassword,
      };
      await apiAccountSettings.validatePassword(tenantName, body);
    },
    onSuccess: () => {
      return true;
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      toast.error(t('Current password is incorrect'));
      throw error; // Throw the error to propagate it
    },
    mutationKey: ['ValidatePassword', { tenant: tenantName }],
  });
};

const { mutate: validatePassword } = useValidatePassword();

const Somefn = async () => {
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      validatePassword(validatePayload, {
        onSuccess: resolve,
        onError: reject,
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    toast.error(t("Something went wrong"));
    return;
  }
};


That's great! Can you please verify if it works for you?

It is working perfectly
